# Angular reactive forms and display errors in span tag

Tags: angular

I have a reactive form like this

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-duplicate-validation-ese9ap?file=src/app/app.component.ts

In the form whenever there is duplicate user i want the isNameDup() to fire for every element in username Array.

I want to indicate to the end user after the input tag that there is an error.

I am not sure what should be the *ngIf clause.

My try is

```
<span *ngIf="creds.get('username').errors?.isNameDup">
              please enter some other name
</span>
```

In the stackbiltz I need to somehow replace line 17 to line 19 so the if condition evaluates to true and the message please enter some other name text appears.

Answer (score 0):

you have to do like this

```
isNameDuplicate:boolean = false;

inputField.valueChanges
    .filter(val => val.length >= 2)
    .debounceTime(500)
    .switchMap(val => this.http.get(`http://myapi.com/${val}`))
    .subscribe(valid => isNameDuplicate = valid);
```

tempalte

```
  <input- Field> //replace this with html inputfield
  <span *ngIf="isNameDuplicate"> duplicate name </span>
```

or [(validation based)](https://alligator.io/angular/async-validators/)

```
   checkDuplicateName(control: AbstractControl) {
    return this.http
      .get('http://myapi.com/${control.value}')
      .delay(1000)
      ..map(res => {
           return !res.isDupliCate ? null : { isNameDuplicate: true };
      });
  }

  //when adding filed
  name: [
    '',
    [Validators.required],
    this.checkDuplicateName.bind(this)
  ]
```

template

```
<input type="text" formControlName="name">
  <div *ngIf="myForm.get('name').errors && myForm.get('name').errors.isNameDuplicate">
    Duplicate name
  </div>
```

Comment: Sorry Pranay this is not working as the control username is in a array

Comment: @jhon.smith - even though its part of array you can add validator to it right , when you are creating control like this  name: [
    '',
    [Validators.required],
    this.checkDuplicateName.bind(this)
  ]

Comment: Hmm Pranay you can give my stackbiltz link a try I don't think so the template that you posted works.

Comment: @jhon.smith - you can check here : https://alligator.io/angular/async-validators/

Comment: Pranay this isn't really related to async-validators at all.Its just that i am not able to get the correct path to make the ngIf true.Thanks for taking a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function isNameDup() {
  const validator: ValidatorFn = (formArray: FormArray) => {  
    const control= formArray.controls
      .map(control => control.value);
      const names = control.map(value=> value.username)
       const hasDuplicate = names.some(
    (name, index) => names.indexOf(name, index + 1) != -1
  );  
     return  hasDuplicate ? { duplicate: true } : null;
  }
  return validator;
}
```

Forked Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-duplicate-validation-f54kxv

Comment: Hi Chellappan Wow almost there, In your stackbiltz example can we have span tag on line 17 instead right after the username input tag and have something like <span *ngIf="credentials.controls.username.errors?,isNameDup">
              please enter some other name
            </span>

Comment: Can we have the isNameDup validator on the username field instead of the creds formArray ?

Comment: Hi Chellapan i have been trying that since a couple of hours and the solution is eluding me I am not sure what should the span tag look like ? Apologies if my question was not clear

Comment: Wait let me check

Comment: Well lets say the user enters two usernames say bob john and bob then right after the third input i.e bob i want to add a span tag and say this is a duplicate by accessing the error from isNameDup

Comment: you want to show error to specific input element when there is error?

Comment: The isNameDup should be attached to the username formcontrol not to the array called credentials.And then use the span tag to print a error message whenever there is a duplicate username